# How to get the product catalog associated to a product set

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

Creating a product set requires associating a product_catalog_id:

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/<PRODUCT_CATALOG_ID>/product_sets
```

Reading an product set having the Facebook id is easy:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/<PRODUCT_SET_ID>
```

Unfortunately, the response for that request contains 3 fields (id, name and filter).

How can I get the product_catalog_id associated to a product set (if I know the product_set_id)?

PS: The documentation does not help with that: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/dynamic-product-ads/product-catalog#productset

Comment: It looks like that functionality is not available. What's the use case where you would know the product_set_id but not the catalog_id? Since the catalog_id is required to both create and fetch the product sets.

Comment: The use case is importing product audiences by their ids. If you want to import a product audience, you need to take the process backwards. So, you need the product set for the audience, then you need the product catalog for the product set.

Answer (score 1):

The catalog ID is not a field of the product set, so you therefore cannot traverse the graph in this way.

The only way to gather this associated is to read read the catalogues in a business, and their product sets to find the correct association unfortunately.

Comment: You are right, yet I was hoping to have another way of importing them.